# Recursive function to return overall overall results

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need a recursive method to roll up all results from a series of paginated calls and returns the complete list of results. Something feels off in the way I am doing it and feel there is a better way to do this, possibly with `Array.reduce`

Any recommendations appreciated.

```
interface Result {
  users: Widget[];
  start: number;
}

interface Widget {
  id: number;
}

// create 3 widgets for test
const widgets = Array(3).fill(null).map((i, index: number) => {
  return {
    id: index + 1,
  } as Widget;
});

const getFromAPI = (start: number = 0): Result => {
  // return 1 at a time from a specified position
  const current = widgets.slice(start, start + 1);
  let nextStart: number | undefined;
  if (start < widgets.length - 1) {
    nextStart = start + 1;
  }

  return {
    users: current,
    start: nextStart,
  }
}

// I don't like that em is outside the scope here
let em: Widget[] = [];
const getWidgets = (start?: number): Widget[] => {
  const result = getFromAPI(start);
  em = [...em, ...result.users];
  if (result.start) {
    getWidgets(result.start);
  }

  return em;
}

const all = getWidgets();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N7K8DN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  Specifically you have a `nextStart` value that can be used before being assigned and you should probably fix that (maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrGolm)?)

Comment: You say you need a *recursive* method; is this a requirement?  You can't use a loop or a something?  (Note that `Array.reduce()` would not be recursive either)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9paow) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on what is missing.

Comment: @jcalz the code above is a minimal reproducible example as shown by the fact that you copied it and ran it in a TS playground without needing modification. Not sure that the observation on nextStart adds any value to the question. WRT to a loop, the code-smell for me is having `em` outside the function.

Comment: yes, that approach of passing in the accumulating array is what I was missing! please pop that into an answer and I will accept. much appreciated

Comment: Sure, I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't like that `em` is outside the scope of `getWidget()` and that you are reassigning it inside the function body and thus relying on [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).  Instead it seems that you want something more [purely functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_programming), without relying on state changes.

If so, then one approach you can take is to make `em` another argument to the function, and have it initially empty, and then returning the recursive result of `getWidgets()` called with the next version of `em`:

```
const getWidgets = (em: Widget[] = [], start?: number): Widget[] => {
  const result = getFromAPI(start);
  const nextEm = [...em, ...result.users];
  return result.start ? getWidgets(nextEm, result.start) : nextEm;
}
```

I've changed the reassignment of `em` to a new variable `nextEm` just in case you want to avoid side effects even within the body of `getWidgets` as well.  It makes the algorithm a little clearer anyway.

You can verify that a call to `getWidgets()` yields the same result as in your example:

```
const all = getWidgets();
console.log(all); // [{ "id": 1}, { "id": 2}, { "id": 3}]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4FcA2ZkDeAUMslhtBgFzIDqwAJgOYRgDaAugNwnIZhwoYAPw0QWALYAjaDwC+RIqEixEKes1aFejMZJlR5igPTHkCKBDiRkAZmQB3RizAZkMAPZRkkfkQQeIPyOzqxuALzIAIJQUHAAngAUtgCUAHQwwDg4ieLZ6RJwAA6JicAANMigDBAAHnrS0CnI4QB82qSWYFhQIB2kVQw01XXIANTIAIzlvHLIcG4aLvIpPP6BwS4AYlAeElEACgCSLciJ-IJgDQanAAwpNOjYeC3txKQBQfgIPZbgp05NK40hgcMAkOcBEJKhchOMpqteDgtCA6mAAMpQq7IcSNbwAHzIIBqmVRDB4pGAMDOsPwAB4QkCMGlkSAmGAABbIAC0CP6pFRtQxWNOtPhkwpyAUnVYPT67wG5EoNB+sQg4BmAz4WLEaMxl01UqICkUn02rCWYVOiQgEholvYHFOnBhWNEOP0TXtoUdr36Zvwlme+Ei212+2OkMuiNItudaQTtsqCbSQdwYDSSqgGG4vC6cuQabwIJFwmQLgdGBtEkqRYztOaNFtRnWX3m2VOFZ9VcRZo8yJZHiYiTg+S4yFMyDYBGQACJGLOaJM5JUZ-OGIvkAAmFeEOcLmi2OROohAA)